# not able to parse values in HOC in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My end goal is to pass coordinates from parent component to pass child component and render again child component.

here is my HOC

```
const Direction = (props) => compose(  
  withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    mapElement: <div   style={{
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        margin: "0px auto",
        position: "absolute"
      }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const DirectionsService = new  window.google.maps.DirectionsService();

      DirectionsService.route({
        origin: new  window.google.maps.LatLng(props.name,101.686855),
        destination: new  window.google.maps.LatLng(3.148780599999999,101.6936573),
        waypoints: 
        [{
            location:new window.google.maps.LatLng(3.145832999999999,101.695556),
            stopover:false
        }],  
        optimizeWaypoints: true, 
        travelMode:  window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      }, (result, status) => {
        if (status ===  window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          this.setState({
            directions: result,
          });
        } else {
          console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
        }
      }). then((response)=> {
        const route = response.routes[0];
        console.log(route);
        alert(route.legs[0].distance.text);
        
        alert(route.legs[0].duration.text);
      })
    }
  })
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={7}
    defaultCenter={new  window.google.maps.LatLng(3.139003,101.686855 )}
  >
  <Marker
            position={{ lat: 3.145832999999999, lng: 101.695556 }}
            
          />
          <Details />
    {props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions} /> }

  </GoogleMap>
//   <Details></Details >
  
);
```

here is my PassCords component

```
export default function PassCords() {
    return (
        // <div>
            <Direction name={'3.139003'} />
        
    )
}
```

here is my FirstScreen component

```
export default function FirstScreen() {
    return (
        <div >
            {/* <SimpleMap /> */}
            {/* < Direction  /> */}
            <PassCords />
            {/* <Details /> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

App.js

```
export default function FirstScreen() {
    return (
        <div >
            {/* <SimpleMap /> */}
            {/* < Direction  /> */}
            <PassCords />
            {/* <Details /> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

error

Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

-at Direction
-at PassCords
-at div
-at FirstScreen
-at div
-at App

Comment: What is `lifecycle` and what exactly are you passing to it? `compose` should take only Higher Order Components, and returns a HOC that you then wrap a react component with. It's unclear what you are trying to do since just about everything about it seems incorrect.

Comment: Drew Reese kindly check the codes again

Comment: Ok, thanks, that is much clearer now. Where is the error occurring, which line of code? Do you have a stacktrace? Does the error go away if you comment out a bunch of the HOCs and simplify the render return? What happens when you incrementally add units of code back in?

Comment: I think it should either be `const Direction = compose(.....` since `compose` returns a React component, or factor out the `props => <GoogleMap .....` into a component and pass this to the `compose` function, or both. Outside this I think we may need a running codesandbox example that reproduces the issue to inspect and debug live.